# Training wav2vec2 for multiple (classification) tasks

Tags: python, pytorch, classification, huggingface

I trained a wav2vec2 model using pytorch and huggingface transformer. Here is the code: https://github.com/padmalcom/wav2vec2-nonverbalvocalization

I now want to train the model on a second tasks, e.g. age classification or speech recognition (ASR).

My problem is, that I do not really understand how I can configure my model to accept a seconds input and train another output. Can anybody give me a short explaination?

I know that I have to use multiple heads in my model and that the thing I want to achieve is called "multi task learning". My problem is, that I don't know how to write the model for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be easier to accomplish if you are ok with giving up some performance for the sake of simplicity.

This answer is formulated based on the assumption that you're new to multi-task / joint learning strategies and are looking for something simple to start with.

## Approach 1

Because ***Wav2Vec2's*** was designed as a ***CTC*** model, you can just easily initialize second classification head with the exact same architecture as [here](https://github.com/padmalcom/wav2vec2-nonverbalvocalization/blob/main/Wav2Vec2ClassificationHead.py#L4), and sample *inputs* and *labels* for both of your tasks at the same time, in the same dataloader. This will get a bit more complicated if you want to do *ASR* as a second task, but would be easy enough if you choose to just focus on Sequence Classification in both cases.

Now, let's say you have two merged datasets, where columns are:

1. audio_path: str
2. label: int
3. task: int

In the DataCollator, you would normally concatenate everything with relative tensors as described [here](https://github.com/padmalcom/wav2vec2-nonverbalvocalization/blob/main/train.py#L93), but with one minor change: you return batched ***task index*** tensor along with ***inputs*** and ***labels***.

Afterwards, you can can reuse that information to split up the ***hidden states*** to route them to different classification heads after [this line](https://github.com/padmalcom/wav2vec2-nonverbalvocalization/blob/main/Wav2Vec2ForSpeechClassification.py#L69). i.e. if your ***task tensor*** looks something like this: `torch.tensor([[0, 0, 1, 1]])`, you can use `hidden_states[:2, :, :]` as a first classification head input, and `hidden_states[2:, :, :]` for second classification head. Same goes for labels as well.

But probably they'll be fairly distributed `([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, ...])` - in this case you can append each of the batches to the relative list and then concatenate them.

*This is to avoid complexity of **multi-task learning** and convert this task into more of **joint-learning** approach for simplicity.*

Your forward pass to classification heads would look like this:

```
hidden_states = self.merged_strategy(hidden_states, mode=self.pooling_mode)
hidden_states_1 = ... # As described above
hidden_states_2 = ... # As described above
labels_1 = ... # As described above
labels_2 = ... # As described above
task_1_logits = self.classifier_1(hidden_states_1)
task_2_logits = self.classifier_2(hidden_states_2)
```

As you get logits for both tasks, you'll need to calculate loss over them separately, and then do either `sum`, `mean` over them, or multiply each of them by some weight in advance.

It would look like this:

```
  loss_1 = loss_fct(logits_1.view(-1, self.num_labels_1), labels_1.view(-1))
  loss_2 = loss_fct(logits_2.view(-1, self.num_labels_2), labels_2.view(-1))
  total_loss = (loss_1 * 0.5) + (loss_2 * 0.5)
```

Please note, that there will be some things to consider anyway, such as - you might not end up with having data for both tasks in some batches in case you're not planning to write custom dataloader.

This approach won't yield SOTA results that you can put into production (at least without lot of further optimizations), but will probably be alright for experimentation and private usage.

## Approach 2

Easier way to go with this is as follows:

1. ***freeze Wav2Vec2Model***
2. Train ***classification head*** for first task and save weights
3. Train ***classification head*** for second task and save weights.
4. Initialize two classification heads during inference and load trained weights accordingly
5. Do forward passes through either of the heads depending on what you want to do with your inputs.

This approach will yield worse results as transformer layers of ***Wav2Vec2*** will not be finetuned.

Comment: Thank you for the effort you put into your answer. Give me some time to understand your tweo approaches.

Comment: Okay, I implemented the model as you proposed. The first question that arose is how I deal with the AutoConfig and my two label lists (here: https://github.com/padmalcom/wav2vec2-nonverbalvocalization/blob/main/train.py#L194). I can only provide one list of labels since the pretrained wav2vec2 model accepts only one list of labels. In Wav2Vec2ForSpeechClassification, I added a second classification head but I'm not sure which labels to pass to the Wav2Vec2Model.